# ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit for Intel Core 2 Duo laptop?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, laptop

I would like to download ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit). The iso file says "ubuntu-12.040desktop-amd64.iso" will it work with Intel Core2 Duo laptop?

Comment: 'amd64' because: whereas AMD followed Intel's lead for 32-bit processors; Intel proposed a different 64-bit design, but ended up adopting the AMD design (more backwards compatible with 32bit).

Answer (score 7):

All Intel Core 2 Duo and Intel Core i3, i5 and i7 support either 32 Bit or 64 bit. You will not have a problem with this. With what you might have a problem is with the amount of memory you need. For 32 Bit the minimum for a good running system is 512MB, the maximum is 4GB. For 64Bit the minimum recommended is 2GB and the maximum is "let your imagination fly!!!". I have tested 64Bit versions on 1GB and they can run very slow sometimes. The more memory the better.

If your Core 2 Duo laptop has at least 4 GB of ram I would recommend 64 bit but since it is a laptop and the more memory you have in a 64 bit the better, I would recommend sticking with the 32 Bit version. You actually don't loose to try both but for your case I would go more with the 32 Bit version (Except if it is some kind of 4GB+ Ram Laptop).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

That is the ISO for the 64bit version. It should work fine

Answer (score 2):

If you got at least 2GB of RAM I highly suggest to go for the 64 bit installation. In theory it is faster than the 32 bit version. If you have 4GB or more than it is actually required to use all the available memory.

In the past there were some problems with 64 bit Ubuntu, mainly because lots of applications didn't support 64 bit yet. Nowadays however, the problems are mostly solved and I never experienced any problems running 64 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I too have a laptop with an Intel Core2 Duo, and that's the file I used; it is running great!  That's the 64-bit version, and despite its name it works on Intel 
CPU's as well as on AMDs.

Answer (score 0):

I got 3 GB RAM on Core 2 duo laptop (old T61) and running 64-bit 12.04 LTS. It works absolutely fine until you run eclipse and web server.

I am planning to revert to 32-bit.

Comment: How will reverting to 32-bit improve system performance? 3 GB of RAM are enough to run 64-bit and don't run out of RAM (2 GB are recommended, but I would rather say 3 GB), which is why some systems deliver poor experience running 64-bit.

Comment: In fact, running 64-bit might actually give you access to a bit more memory - some laptop designs have 4GB installed RAM but under 32-bits not all is visible due to the need to be able to 'see' graphics memory as well.